# Theme 'Default' cannot be found in the application

Tags: c#, episerver

I have the error:

```
Theme 'Default' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories
Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Theme 'Default' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.]
   System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(String themeName) +920
   System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(HttpContext context, String themeName) +73
   System.Web.UI.Page.InitializeThemes() +8699455
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +38
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +282
```

My problem is, I never changed the Theme.
I get this error just sometimes, in different pages. I don't know if this is a bug in one of the software ( EpiServer 6, IIS, Windows Server) or if I have a problem the Server's HDD.

Some one have a idea about this problem.
I know this is a trick questions, but I have no idea about this issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the App_Themes folder? My previous EPi 6 projects I've just removed that folder completely. If you have it, you can try renaming it to something else and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes I have. I sent today an email to EpiServer Support asking if the guys there have some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your episerver.config and the virtual path is correct

```
<add virtualPath="~/App_Themes/Default/" physicalPath="C:\Program Files\EPiServer\CMS\6.1.379.0\application\App_Themes\Default" name="App_Themes_Default" type="EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathNonUnifiedProvider,EPiServer" />
```

Can get confused if you switch between 64-bit and 32-bit machines

Comment: yes, is there. I believe the problem is a HDD issue.